# Why I get "dlib isn't going to use CUDA" when I compile dlib python interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, dlib

I have compiled dlib 19.10 using cmake 3.11.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 with CUDA 9.1 enabled. It went well and didn't get any problems!

Here the output of running `cmake ..`

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Looking for png_create_read_struct
-- Looking for png_create_read_struct - found
-- Looking for jpeg_read_header
-- Looking for jpeg_read_header - found
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'cblas'
--   No package 'cblas' found
-- Checking for module 'lapack'
--   Found lapack, version 0.2.18
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of void*
-- Check size of void* - done
-- Found OpenBLAS library
-- Looking for sgetrf_single
-- Looking for sgetrf_single - found
-- Using OpenBLAS's built in LAPACK
-- Looking for cblas_ddot
-- Looking for cblas_ddot - found
-- Looking for sgesv
-- Looking for sgesv - not found
-- Looking for sgesv_
-- Looking for sgesv_ - not found
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda-9.1 (found suitable version "9.1", minimum required is "7.5") 
-- Looking for cuDNN install...
-- Found cuDNN: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so
-- Building a CUDA test project to see if your compiler is compatible with CUDA...
-- Checking if you have the right version of cuDNN installed.
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.0") 
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.0") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.0")  
-- Enabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL USE CUDA
-- C++11 activated.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/peshmerge/Downloads/dlib-19.10/build
```

But when I run `sudo python3.5 setup.py install` I get a message that CUDA was found, but it won't be used:

```
-- *** CUDA was found but your compiler failed to compile a simple CUDA program so dlib isn't going to use CUDA.
```

While it shows me before that CUDA and also CuDNN were found:

```
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local (found suitable version "9.1", minimum required is "7.5") 
-- Looking for cuDNN install...
-- Found cuDNN: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so
```

Here is the whole output when I run `sudo python3.5 setup.py install`:

```
peshmerge@darkage-x580vd:~/Downloads/dlib-19.10$ sudo python3.5 setup.py install
running install
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
/usr/bin/python3.5 -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating dlib.egg-info
writing dlib.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to dlib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to dlib.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
package init file 'dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /home/peshmerge/Downloads/dlib-19.10/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/peshmerge/Downloads/dlib-19.10/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.5 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.5 (found version "3.5.2") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so
-- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG
-- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG - Success
-- pybind11 v2.2.2
-- Enabling SSE4 instructions
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Looking for png_create_read_struct
-- Looking for png_create_read_struct - found
-- Looking for jpeg_read_header
-- Looking for jpeg_read_header - found
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'cblas'
--   No package 'cblas' found
-- Checking for module 'lapack'
--   Found lapack, version 0.2.18
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of void*
-- Check size of void* - done
-- Found OpenBLAS library
-- Looking for sgetrf_single
-- Looking for sgetrf_single - found
-- Using OpenBLAS's built in LAPACK
-- Looking for cblas_ddot
-- Looking for cblas_ddot - found
-- Looking for sgesv
-- Looking for sgesv - not found
-- Looking for sgesv_
-- Looking for sgesv_ - not found
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local (found suitable version "9.1", minimum required is "7.5") 
-- Looking for cuDNN install...
-- Found cuDNN: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so
-- Building a CUDA test project to see if your compiler is compatible with CUDA...
-- *****************************************************************************************************************
-- *** CUDA was found but your compiler failed to compile a simple CUDA program so dlib isn't going to use CUDA. 
-- *** The output of the failed CUDA test compile is shown below: 
-- ***   Change Dir: /home/peshmerge/Downloads/dlib-19.10/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/dlib_build/cuda_test_build
   ***   
   ***   Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make"
   ***   [ 50%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/cuda_test_generated_cuda_test.cu.o
   ***   nvcc fatal   : Path to libdevice library not specified
   ***   CMake Error at cuda_test_generated_cuda_test.cu.o.cmake:275 (message):
   ***     Error generating file
   ***     /home/peshmerge/Downloads/dlib-19.10/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/dlib_build/cuda_test_build/CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir//./cuda_test_generated_cuda_test.cu.o
   ***   
   ***   
   ***   CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/build.make:63: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/cuda_test_generated_cuda_test.cu.o' failed
   ***   make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/cuda_test_generated_cuda_test.cu.o] Error 1
   ***   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/all' failed
   ***   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cuda_test.dir/all] Error 2
   ***   Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
   ***   make: *** [all] Error 2
   ***   
-- *****************************************************************************************************************
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.0") 
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.0") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.0")  
-- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
-- C++11 activated.
-- Found Python with installed numpy package
-- Numpy include path '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include'
-- Performing Test HAS_FLTO
-- Performing Test HAS_FLTO - Success
-- LTO enabled
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/peshmerge/Downloads/dlib-19.10/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- -j8'
Scanning dependencies of target dlib
[  1%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bigint/bigint_kernel_2.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bit_stream/bit_stream_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_1.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/entropy_encoder/entropy_encoder_kernel_2.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/md5/md5_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/tokenizer/tokenizer_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/unicode/unicode.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/image_dataset_metadata.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/data_io/mnist.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/global_optimization/global_function_search.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/filtering/kalman_filter.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/test_for_odr_violations.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/bsp/bsp.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_2.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dir_nav/dir_nav_extensions.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/linker/linker_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/extra_logger_headers.cpp.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/logger/logger_config_file.cpp.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/misc_api/misc_api_kernel_2.cpp.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_extensions.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockets/sockets_kernel_2.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/sockstreambuf/sockstreambuf_unbuffered.cpp.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_kernel.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_iostream.cpp.o
[ 41%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/server/server_http.cpp.o
[ 43%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/multithreaded_object_extension.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threaded_object_extension.cpp.o
[ 45%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_2.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/threads_kernel_shared.cpp.o
[ 49%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/thread_pool_extension.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/threads/async.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/timer/timer.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/stack_trace.cpp.o
[ 54%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dnn/cpu_dlib.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/dnn/tensor_tools.cpp.o
[ 56%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/fonts.cpp.o
[ 58%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/widgets.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/drawable.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/canvas_drawing.cpp.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/style.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_widgets/base_widgets.cpp.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_1.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/png_loader.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_png.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_loader/jpeg_loader.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/image_saver/save_jpeg.cpp.o
[ 71%] Linking CXX static library libdlib.a
[ 71%] Built target dlib
Scanning dependencies of target dlib_python
[ 72%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/dlib.cpp.o
[ 74%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/matrix.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/vector.cpp.o
[ 76%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/svm_c_trainer.cpp.o
[ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/svm_rank_trainer.cpp.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/decision_functions.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/other.cpp.o
[ 81%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/basic.cpp.o
[ 82%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/cca.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/sequence_segmenter.cpp.o
[ 85%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/svm_struct.cpp.o
[ 86%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/image.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/rectangles.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/object_detection.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/shape_predictor.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/correlation_tracker.cpp.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/face_recognition.cpp.o
[ 93%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/cnn_face_detector.cpp.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/global_optimization.cpp.o
[ 96%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/image_dataset_metadata.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/numpy_returns.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dlib_python.dir/src/gui.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared module /home/peshmerge/Downloads/dlib-19.10/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/dlib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
[100%] Built target dlib_python
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/dlib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating stub loader for dlib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/dlib.py to dlib.cpython-35.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying dlib.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying dlib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying dlib.egg-info/not-zip-safe -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying dlib.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
creating dist
creating 'dist/dlib-19.10.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing dlib-19.10.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg
creating /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dlib-19.10.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg
Extracting dlib-19.10.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg to /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Adding dlib 19.10.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dlib-19.10.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for dlib==19.10.0
Finished processing dependencies for dlib==19.10.0
```

If I run `setup.py` using the option `--yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS` I don't get any message about using CUDA. I run it like this:

```
sudo python3.5 setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS
```

I don't know what does it cause when I use that flag, I am not sure if it disable compiling it using CUDA or not!

Does anyone has an idea why it succeeds to find CUDA when building Dlib and fails when I want to Compile Dlib's Python Interface?

I have tried to compile Dlib's Python Interface using Cmake as suggested here [Installation guide by dlib.net](http://dlib.net/compile.html), but it fails too!

**EDIT1**

I run `sudo python3.5 setup.py install --clean`

and I got :

```
running install
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
/usr/bin/py -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dependency_links to dlib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing dlib.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to dlib.egg-info/top_level.txt
package init file 'dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
Removing old directory /home/peshmerge/Downloads/dlib-19.10/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /home/peshmerge/Downloads/dlib-19.10/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/peshmerge/Downloads/dlib-19.10/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/py -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/py (found version "3.5.2") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so
-- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG
-- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG - Success
-- pybind11 v2.2.2
-- Enabling SSE4 instructions
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Looking for png_create_read_struct
-- Looking for png_create_read_struct - found
-- Looking for jpeg_read_header
-- Looking for jpeg_read_header - found
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'cblas'
--   No package 'cblas' found
-- Checking for module 'lapack'
--   Found lapack, version 0.2.18
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of void*
-- Check size of void* - done
-- Found OpenBLAS library
-- Looking for sgetrf_single
-- Looking for sgetrf_single - found
-- Using OpenBLAS's built in LAPACK
-- Looking for cblas_ddot
-- Looking for cblas_ddot - found
-- Looking for sgesv
-- Looking for sgesv - not found
-- Looking for sgesv_
-- Looking for sgesv_ - not found
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (found suitable version "9.1", minimum required is "7.5")
-- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
-- C++11 activated.
-- Found Python with installed numpy package
-- Numpy include path '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include'
-- Performing Test HAS_FLTO
-- Performing Test HAS_FLTO - Success
-- LTO enabled
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/peshmerge/Downloads/dlib-19.10/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- -j8'
Scanning dependencies of target dlib
```

It's now complaining about

```
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (found suitable version "9.1", minimum required is "7.5")
```

While `CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY` are defined in my environments

```
echo $CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY && echo $CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS
/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcudart.so
/usr/local/cuda-9.1/include
```

**EdIT2:**
Running `python3.5 setup.py install --clean` without `sudo` results

```
running install
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/test-easy-install-7244.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

**EDIT3:**
I have completed compiling dlib using cmake using the following actions:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Give —clean. You probably have some busted thing in the build folder.

Comment: I did, check the update! It's complaining now about not finding CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS & CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY while they are set!
Can I pass those two variables hardcoded to setup.py?

Comment: Run this all without sudo

Comment: I got permission denied!

Comment: Can I pass CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS & CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY variables hardcoded to setup.py?

Comment: That’s not the problem. If it works outside setup.py it should work inside. So you have to ask, what am I doing different?  Sudo is a difference. Run it all in a new folder without sudo and see if it builds.

Comment: I got the same result! Permission Denied! 
Check EDIT3. I have built dlib following those steps!

Comment: What about cuda? What did it say about cuda?

Comment: It did say nothing about Cuda when I run it without `sudo`. Please check EDIT2 for the output!

Comment: Just use build instead of install.

Comment: I built instead of installed, but when I run setup.py I get the same error `Permission Denied`. He has to write to to `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/`. Without `sudo` it can't!

Comment: No. Building doesn’t write there. You don’t need sudo to build. Download it again and start from a fresh folder.

Comment: I used a new and fresh folder! 
I just run `cmake ..` then `cmake --build . --config Release`. After that I run `python3.5 setup.py install` Then I got the error message `Permission denied` because he still wants to acces ` /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/`

Comment: Is there another way for compiling the Python interface?

Comment: Run python setup.py build —clean. What is the output?

Comment: I get Permission denied as described in EDIT2

Comment: @DavisKing I have compiled Dlib with CUDA 9.0 and it worked! I think there is a problem or compatibility issue with CUDA 9.1

Answer (score 0):

**To build DLIB Python module with CUDA for Python 3.x.**

```
sudo python3 setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS --yes DLIB_USE_CUDA
```

Note: It is not required to build CUDA before building the Python module.

Comment: According to Davis King, as mentioned here https://peshmerge.io/how-to-build-dlib-on-linux-ubuntu-18-04-using-cmake-with-avx-support-and-install-its-python-api/#comment-44
you only need to run `python setup.py install` assuming python is an alias for python3 !